# High-pass filtering in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

To make a 3x3 high-pass filter kernel in OpenCV, I use the following code (for Android):

```
Mat kernel = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32FC1);
float[] data = {0, -1, 0, -1, 4, -1, 0, -1, 0};
kernel.put(0, 0, data);
```

I then filter using the kernel:

```
Imgproc.filter2D(image, image, -1, kernel);
```

Is there a way to automatically generate larger high-pass kernels in OpenCV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are number of different high-pass filters implemented in opencv. The one you have set for your example is Laplacian:

```
0  1  0
1 -4  1
0  1  0
```

You can use the [`Laplacian`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#laplacian) function of opencv which has the `ksize` parameter. You must be able to apply larger Laplacian kernels by manipulating that parameter.

If you're interested in other high-pass filters, opencv has Canny, Sobel, etc.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm going to use Safir's answer, I did find a function [getDerivKernels()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_image_filtering.html#getDerivKernels) which appears to generate the kernel matrices themselves, albeit only for Sobel or Scharr filters and only in particular sizes.